# Kentico - Repeater With Custom Query Issue

Tags: kentico

I have this query below in a custom query repeater to display all articles that have the same value under `PracticeAreas` as the current one. `PracticeAreas` has multiple checkboxes - and this is the problem.

```
SELECT ArticleTitle, NodeAliasPath FROM my_articles 
JOIN view_cms_tree_joined
ON ArticlesID = DocumentForeignKeyValue
where classname = 'my.articles' and 
##WHERE##
```

and have this in the WHERE condition:

```
PracticeAreas = '{%CurrentDocument.PracticeAreas#%}' and NodeID != {%CurrentDocument.NodeID#%}
```

Example: Article#1 has 1 and 2 checked under PracticeAreas; Article#2 has 1 checked; Article#3 has 1 and 2 checked.

Result: Only Article#1 and Article#3 are considered related from my code. But
what I really wanted is all 3 articles above to be related because they all have one same PracticeArea which is checkbox 1. Is this possible? Hope it's clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, To start off you can use the view (made by Kentico) for your class, in your case it will probably be view_my_atricles_joined. it has all the column you need. 
I am not quite sure what PracticeAreas contains as a string. 
If I assume this a list of some IDs (CSV)  for ex.: CSV = 'ID1,ID2,ID3,...ID100'

let say you article has  'ID1,ID3' then your 'WHERE' should look like :
   WHERE PATINDEX(',ID1,', ',' + CSV + ',') > 0 
   OR PATINDEX(',ID3,', ',' + CSV + ',') > 0

Comment: Those views are not available in v9 any longer so the query base query the OP has is the best one to start with.